# How to perform Lemmatization with POS tagging in Pyspark dataframe (Without using Pandas)

Tags: pyspark, nltk, lemmatization

How to perform Lemmatization with POS tagging in Pyspark dataframe (Without using Pandas)

I am new to pyspark and trying out lemmatization with Parts of speech tagging. My data in in tabular format. Having a column as text. I have cleaned the text but unable to Lemmatize the tokens with parts of speech.

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.johnsnowlabs.com/spark-nlp/

Comment: @cronoik I am trying to write a code for it.  johnsnowlabs.com/spark-nlp does not solves the problem.

Comment: The spark-nlp package contains a POS-tagger. Isn't that what you want or do you want to write your own tagger? If that is the case, it would help if you include some example data and what you have tried by your own so far.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Spark-NLP](https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/2020/03/19/explain_document_dl.html) library, which contains lots of pretrained models, for example for English language, you can do the following:

```
pipeline = PretrainedPipeline('explain_document_dl', lang = 'en')

annotations =  pipeline.fullAnnotate("""French author who helped pioner the science-fiction genre. Verne wrate about space, air, and underwater travel before navigable aircrast and practical submarines were invented, and before any means of space travel had been devised.""")[0]

annotations.keys()
```

Which performs multiple NLP tasks including lemmatization and POS:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                text|            document|            sentence|               token|               spell|              lemmas|               stems|                 pos|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|French author who...|[[document, 0, 23...|[[document, 0, 57...|[[token, 0, 5, Fr...|[[token, 0, 5, Fr...|[[token, 0, 5, Fr...|[[token, 0, 5, fr...|[[pos, 0, 5, JJ, ...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```